# Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but List<SportNewsResponse>? was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, inferred-type

I am developing news app and I am getting following error in my MainViewModel.kt class
 Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but List? was expected

below My MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface

) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    private val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    private val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<SportNewsResponse>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { sportNewsInterface.getNews()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {


                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data
                }
                is UseCaseResult.Error -> showError.value = result.exception.message
                 }
                }
            }



    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

below UserCaseResult.kt

```
sealed class UseCaseResult<out T : Any> {
    class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : UseCaseResult<List<SportNewsResponse>>()

    class Error(val exception: Throwable) : UseCaseResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your `Success` class. You're defining `val data` with generic type `T` which is upper bounded by `Any`. And in the `when` block, while you want to check whether it is an instance of `UseCaseResult.Success` or not, you are using a star projection which causes the compiler to infer the result with the upper bound: `UseCaseResult.Success<Any>`. So the type of `result.data` will be inferred as `Any`.

The solution would be:

- If `UseCaseResult.Success` only has a list typed data, you should omit the generic type (currently generic type in your definition of `Success` class makes no sense) :

  ```
  class Success(val data: List<SportNewsResponse>) : UseCaseResult<List<SportNewsResponse>>()
  ```

  or:

  ```
  class Success<out T: Any>(val data: List<T>) : UseCaseResult<List<T>>()
  ```
- Or you can simply change the when clause to this:

  ```
  is UseCaseResult.Success<List<SportNewsResponse>> -> {
                      sportList.value = result.data
                  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, I cleared the build and then built it one more time and it worked.